# React JS Cart - Unable to view items in cart- Getting undefined error

Tags: reactjs, cart

I am having an issue where cartList is initialized as [], I see the cartList being updated by the context code and reducer, but when I try to display the cart items in my cart page using useCart(), it says cartList is undefined.
Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

I tried changing the createContext method and checked my context and reducer code, but everything seems fine.
CartContext.js

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/km-js-kktvgz?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvm0006356k6k16a98y%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0002356kbpxpin45%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0004356kwy5rmmws%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvm0005356k8tpiiluq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsudvlvl0002356kbpxpin45%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0001356k025jqkuf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0002356kbpxpin45%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0001356k025jqkuf%2522%257D%252C%2522clsudvlvm0005356k8tpiiluq%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvm0005356k8tpiiluq%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsudvlvl0004356kwy5rmmws%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0003356kigy0s9jp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0004356kwy5rmmws%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsudvlvl0003356kigy0s9jp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D

```
const cartInitialState = {
    cartList: [],
    total: 0
}

const CartContext = createContext();

export const CartProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, cartInitialState);

    function addToCart(product){
        const updatedList = state.cartList.concat(product);
        const updatedTotal = state.total + product.price;
        console.table(updatedList);
--------------------------------------------------------------------
cartReducer.js
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type){

        case "ADD_TO_CART":
            console.table(payload.products);
            return {...state, cartList: payload.products, total: payload.total}
---------------------------------------------------
cartList.js
import { useState } from "react"
import { useCart } from "../../../context";
import { CartCard } from "./CartCard";
import { Checkout } from "./Checkout";

export const CartList = () => {
  const [checkout, setCheckout] = useState(false);
  const { productList, total } = useCart();

  console.table(productList);

  return (

    <>
      <section>
        <p className="text-2xl text-center font-semibold dark:text-slate-100 my-10 underline underline-offset-8">
          My Cart ({productList})
        </p>
      </section>
```

---

I am enclosing my App like so using Cart.Provider, in my index.js

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <CartProvider> 
     <FilterProvider> 
     <ToastContainer closeButton={false} autoClose={3000} position={"top-right"} />
     <App />
     </FilterProvider>
     </CartProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: You need to add the relevant code to your question. In this case how you're providing the context to your app and how you're accessing it, and whatever else you're trying

Comment: can you please add your code in codesandbox and share the link here. that would be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: I have added the relevant code in codesandbox.. please take a look.

Comment: One of the items in context was coming as undefined in the components. I accessed it using: state.cartList instead of cartList and it is now fine.Still not sure why cartList is coming as empty.